# Is there a way to query by id/pk/some lookup in 1 query rather than getting all nodes filtered and using the id?

Tags: django, graphql, relay, graphene-python

https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/349
http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-relay/

This queries all ingredients and then grab the specific ingredient using the previous query. Is this a normal design pattern in Relay/Graphene or can it be done in 1 query?

```
query {
  allIngredients {
    edges {
      node {
        id,
        name
      }
    }
  }
}

query {
  # Graphene creates globally unique IDs for all objects.
  # You may need to copy this value from the results of the first query
  ingredient(id: "SW5ncmVkaWVudE5vZGU6MQ==") {
    name
  }
}
```

Comment: The second query works without the first query, if that's what you're asking.  But somehow you have to get the id in order to do the second query.

Comment: @MarkChackerian - yeah, let's say I load the slug of the page. Would the most optimal thing to do be to filter for the slug and grab the first result (if it's a unique slug)? I guess what I'm wondering is if query ingredient is the same like Queryset.get which actually uses filter under the hood and if query ingredients is like Queryset.filter?

Comment: Presuming that slugs are unique, it seems that getting the first result from `{ingredients (slug:"myslug") ..` is a fine solution for what you need.  Whether or not this is the "most optimal thing" depends on what you are trying to optimize for...number of HTTP requests?